# why does cdr return a list of one element?

Tags: elisp

I have the following code:

```
(progn 3 4)                ;; => 4 
(list 1 (progn 3 4))       ;; => (1 4) 
(car (list 1 (progn 3 4))) ;; => 1
```

I understand these return values.  But why does the following:

```
(cdr (list 1 (progn 3 4))  ;; => (4)
```

Return `(4)` rather than `4`?  I would have thought `4`, so what am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Note that this is not Emacs-specific, the same rule applies to all Lisps. I'd recommend reading some intro to lisp programming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the docstring for `cdr`:

> (cdr LIST)
>
> Return the cdr of LIST.  If arg is nil, return nil.
>   Error if arg is not nil and not a cons cell.  See also `cdr-safe'.
>
> See Info node `(elisp)Cons Cells' for a discussion of related basic
>   Lisp concepts such as cdr, car, cons cell and list.

`cdr` returns the second slot of the `cons` cell, which is referring to the rest of the list -- in your case, the rest of the list is one element long, but it's still a list.

Look at the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Elements.html) for more information on `cons` cells.  In particular:

*Function: cdr cons-cell*

> This function returns the value referred to by the second slot of the 
>   cons cell cons-cell. In other words, it returns the CDR of cons-cell.
>
> As a special case, if cons-cell is nil, this function returns nil; therefore, any list is a valid argument. An error is signaled if the argument is not a cons cell or nil.

```
(cdr '(a b c))
     ⇒ (b c)
```

Answer (score 6):

When given a list `cdr` returns a *list* from second element to the end:

```lisp
(car '(1 2 3)) ; ⇒ 1
(cdr '(1 2 3)) ; ⇒ (2 3)
```

Exceptions to this include:

- lists of fewer than two elements:

  ```lisp
  (cdr nil)  ; ⇒ nil
  (cdr '(1)) ; ⇒ nil
  ```
- things like `'(1 . 2)` (which are produced with e.g. `(cons 1 2)`):

  ```lisp
  (cdr '(1 . 2)) ; ⇒ 2
  ```

Comment: I don't think it's good to generalize because it'll only confuse people when it returns `nil` or an atom.

Comment: What is with `(cdr (cons 1 2))`?? Please, delete this non-answer.

Comment: @Tobias: seems to be fixed.

Comment: @nanny: now I added this case.

Comment: `(listp (cons 1 2))` rightfully returns `t` and `(listp nil)`, too.

Comment: @Adobe Sure, but the point is that your answer does answer the original question "*Why* does cdr return a list?" Also, `(cdr '(1 . 2))` returns yet another different thing: `2`.

Comment: `'(1 . 2)` is not an association list. The association list closest to this expression would be: `'((1 . 2))`.

Comment: "lists which `cons` produces" is also not working. A common way to extent a list is `(setq listVar (cons newEntry listVar))` with `listVar` holding a list. The `cdr` is just some piece of memory that can hold whatever you like. Maybe, it /most often/ holds `nil` or another cons, i.e. a list.

Comment: I think the questions calls for a technical answer, and we should avoid hand-waving. This is why I downvoted this answer.

Comment: @YoungFrog: you should not be satisfied with anything less than a source code of `cdr` then.

Comment: @Adobe What I am satisfied with is besides the point. The system asked me to comment because of my downvote, and I complied. I'm not attacking you or your answer, I just think it's inadequate.

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but I may as well explain why `cdr` acts the way it does in case someone Googles the question later...

`cdr` acts this way because lists in Lisps like Elisp are not quite lists like how you would imagine them, they are actually made up of things called [cons cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons).

Essentially, when you make a list, it isn't a simple collection of items, one after another--it's actually just a chain of tiny lists, each only capable of holding two values. These pairs are the "cons cells".

In each pair, the first value holds the value of the list at that point, and the second holds either "`nil`" (End of the list), or a reference to another cons cell (The next item in the list).

So:

```lisp
ELISP> (list 1)
(1)
```

Is the same as:

```lisp
ELISP> (cons 1 nil)
(1)
```

And:

```lisp
ELISP> (list 1 4)
(1 4)
```

Is the same as:

```lisp
ELISP> (cons 1 (cons 4 nil))
(1 4)
```

...and so forth.

Now, what [`car` and `cdr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR) do is take the first and second values of these cons cells.

So, looking at your list when expanded to cons cells (That's `(cons 1 (cons 4 nil))`):

```lisp
ELISP> (car (cons 1 (cons 4 nil)))
1
```

Because the first value of the outer `cons` is "`1`", and:

```lisp
ELISP> (cdr (cons 1 (cons 4 nil)))
(4)
```

Because the second value of the outer `cons` is "`(cons 4 nil)`" and:

```lisp
ELISP> (cons 4 nil)
(4)
```

It is possible for a `cdr` to hold something other than `nil` or a reference to another cons cell, but these are not the same type of list, but rather a "dotted pair":

```lisp
ELISP> (cons 1 4)
(1 . 4)
ELISP> (car (cons 1 4))
1
ELISP> (cdr (cons 1 4))
4
```

Hopefully this clears some things up..!

Comment: "tiny lists" confuses more than it helps.  Would be an improvement to just replace with "chain of cons cells".  Because that's what any list in any Lisp is.

Comment: What's the result of (cdddr '(1 2 3 . 4))?  (And yes, valid Elisp, just tested :D)

Comment: Well, I said cons cells were basically "tiny lists that can only hold two values" because I was assuming the reader didn't know what a cons cell was. With that in mind, if you can think of a better way of explaining them, feel free to submit an edit to the answer.

Comment: I personally liked the "tiny lists" explanation; easier to connect the dots (no pun intended) when put that way